# Import and "name" a key and use it for various purposes in GnuPG

Tags: gnupg

Is there a way to import a key and "label it" with a name, to be able to use it to encrypt data with that name?

Answer (score 1):

No, GnuPG does not have such a feature. The only "label" a key can have are user IDs, and adding one requires access to the private key.

Depending on your use case, you might be able to do some kind of external aliasing which resolves the labels to fingerprints (read through ["What is an OpenPGP Key ID collision?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837) before using short key IDs), which GnuPG also accepts instead of user IDs for selecting recipients. How to do so depends on the specific application and will hardly be possible for GUI applications, while finding a solution for command line interfaces is rather likely.